# 401 when creating a modern site using App-Only using Office Pnp Sites Core

Tags: sharepoint, csom

So, I am using method number 2 here:
https://www.vrdmn.com/2019/01/working-with-application-permissions.html

My code is as follows:

```
string siteUrl = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/test212/";
            string siteUrl2 = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/test2122/";

            //Client id and Client secret created through appregnew.aspx and permissions granted through appinv.aspx
            var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

            //PnP Core method
            ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "xx", "xx");

            var teamNoGroupSiteResult = await clientContext.CreateSiteAsync(new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites.TeamNoGroupSiteCollectionCreationInformation()
            {
                Url = siteUrl,
                Title = "Team no group Site Test",
                Description = "Site description",
                Lcid = 1033
            });

            var communicationSiteResult = await clientContext.CreateSiteAsync(new OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites.CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation()
            {
                Url = siteUrl2,
                Title = "Modern no group Site Test",
                Description = "Site description",
                Lcid 
 });
```

SO, I created the app only registration in my tenant, then I tried this code and it says I am unauthorized.

The error I get is:

```
 {
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "Token request failed.",
      "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException",
      "StackTrace": "   at SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)\r\n   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Utilities.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)\r\n   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.EnsureToken(String siteUrl, String realm, String appId, String appSecret, String acsHostUrl, String globalEndPointPrefix)\r\n   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(String siteUrl, String realm, String appId, String appSecret, String acsHostUrl, String globalEndPointPrefix)\r\n   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(String siteUrl, String appId, String appSecret)\r\n   at LuloWebApi.Controllers.TenantController.<Test>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\levalencia30\\Source\\Repos\\LuloBackend\\TenantManagementWebApi\\Controllers\\TenantController.cs:line 42\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
      "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at SharePointPnP.IdentityModel.Extensions.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Could you share the App XML you are using? In which level you registered your App. It should be created in the Admin center with access to the Tenant level.

Comment: what app xml? it has full tenant permissions

Comment: Permission XML which you are using in the Appinv.aspx page?

Comment: Client secret generated for a client ID expires after one year.A new client ID should be re-generated and assigned to this client ID. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1401) it isn't possible using PnP as of yet. There is code change to address it in the Dev branch though so you could copy it and create your own CreateSiteAsync extension method and copy the sitecollection.cs into your own project.

Failing that you could call the Rest API yourself based on the code in the relevant CreateAsync method.

Edit: I could never get app only with a ClientId and secret to work. Try ClientId and Cert method outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

Comment: you are mentioning my own question here ? self link

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that PnP. You can try a code that changes it in the dev branch. This would allow you to copy it and make a CreateSiteAsync extension method and simply copy sitecollction.cs to your project.